# Setting up and running docker images: basic questions

Tags: docker

I'm a bit confused as to how to go ahead with docker.

I can build an image with the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM condaforge/mambaforge:4.10.1-0

# Use bash as shell
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /work_dir

# Install vim
RUN ["apt-get", "update"]
RUN ["apt-get", "install", "-y", "vim"]

# Start Bash shell by default
CMD /bin/bash
```

I build it with `docker build --rm . -t some_docker` but then I'd like to enter the container, and install things individually interactively, so that later on I can export the whole image with all additional installations. So I then can start it interactively with `docker run -it some_docker`, after which I do my things. I would then like to export it.

So here are my specific questions:

- Is there an easier way to build (and keep) the image available so that then I can come back to it at another point? When I run `docker ps -a` I see so many images that I dont know what they do since many of them dont have any tag.
- After building I get the warning `Use 'docker scan' to run Snyk tests against images to find vulnerabilities and learn how to fix them`. Is this a problem and if so, how to solve it?
- How can I specify in my Dockerfile (or `docker build`?) that ports for rstudio should be open? I saw that `docker-compose` allows you to specify `ports: 8787:8787`, how do I do it in here?

Comment: "*So here are my specific questions: ...*" - Please read: [Can I ask only one question per post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post)

Comment: "*When I run `docker ps -a` I see so many images*" - Those are not images, those are containers. --- "*After building I get the warning `Use 'docker scan' to run Snyk tests against images to find vulnerabilities and learn how to fix them`. Is this a problem and if so, how to solve it?"* - If there are vulnerabilities then yes, they should be closed. To find them (if any) run the command. - "*How can I specify in my Dockerfile (or `docker build`?) that ports for rstudio should be open?*" - [Dockerfile documentation: `EXPOSE`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. With `docker ps -a`, what you're seeing is container rather than images. To list images, use `docker image ls` instead. Whether you should delete images depends on what containers you're going to run in the future. Docker uses layer architecture with Copy-on-write strategy. So for example, in the future, if you want to use the image `FROM condaforge/mambaforge:4.10.1-0`, docker won't have to download and install it again. Your example is fairly simple, but with more complicated apps, it may take a lot of time to build images and run container from scratch (the longest I have experienced is about 30 mins). However, if storage is your concern, just go ahead delete images that you don't use very often. [Read more](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/)
2. Yes, of course. However, it depends on the details that you have from `docker scan`. To see more details, you can run `docker scan --file PATH_TO_DOCKERFILE DOCKER_IMAGE`. [Read more](https://docs.docker.com/engine/scan/)
3. Dockerfile is for building images, and Docker-compose file is for orchestrating containers. That's why you cannot publish ports in Dockerfile. This also creates problems like security or conflicts. All you can do is to `expose` container ports, then run `docker run -d -P --name app_name app_image_name` to publish all ports exposed in the container.